# how to display the data returned by get_by_user_id() in DataMapper Code Igniter?

Tags: database, codeigniter, datamapper

I am new to code igniter data mapper. I  have a table called user, and I am trying to retrieve data from the database table and show them to the user. 
Here is what I have in the model:

```
    $u=new User();
$results=$u->get_by_user_id($id); 
    //$results here will be set to huge bunch of none sense data( which also includes the     row that I am looking for as well) 

if ($u->exists())
{ 

 foreach ($results->all as $row){
      $data['user']['first_name']=($row->user_first); //this  where I am stuck ..
  $data['user']['last_name']=($row->user_last);//this is also where I am stuck..

}
```

I don't know how to treat results to get a required fields I am looking for and store them in the $data I am passing to the user to view. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `get_by_x()` on the model, the fields will be populated with data and you can access them like this:

```
$u = new User();
$u->get_by_user_id($id);
if($u->exists())
{
    // you can access the table columns as object fields
    $data['user']['first'] = $u->first;
    $data['user']['last'] = $u->last;
}
else
{
    $data['error'] = 'No such user!';
}
```

Have a look at the documentation which is really helpful: see [Get](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/get.html) and Get By.

Also, DataMapper expects all tables to have an `id` column: see [Table Naming Rules](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/database.html). If your column is named `id` you should then call `$u->get_by_id($id)` instead of `$u->get_by_user_id($id)`.